# How do I return data from a $http.get() inside a factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a lot of trouble with this and I can't seem to find anything here on SO or Google that helps me spot what I'm doing wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="testApp">
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div data-ng-controller="myController">
         {{test}}<br/>
         {{test2}}<br/>
         {{test3}}
         <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="member in members">{{ member.firstname}}</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         angular.module('testApp', ['memberFactory']);

         angular.module('testApp',[])
         .factory('memberFactory', function($http){

            var obj = {};
            obj.data = "abcd";
            obj.getResponse = function(){
                var temp = {};
                $http.get('hello.php').success(function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        temp =data;

                });

                return "some return value";
            }

            return obj
         });

         function myController($scope, memberFactory){ 
            $scope.test= "testString";
            $scope.test2= memberFactory.data;
            $scope.test3= memberFactory.getResponse();

         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

the `return "some return value";` works but when I try to return temp, its null. I have tried various ways to get this to work but I just can't seem to set the temp value inside the `$http.get()` function

It is probably something simple (or a silly mistake/misguided approach on my part). Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you are using angular 1.0.1, this will break in 1.3..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use defer:

```
obj.getResponse = function(){                 
    var temp = {};
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get('hello.php').success(function(data){
            alert(data);
            temp =data;
            defer.resolve(data);

    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: What is $q? I'm getting not defined. is this another library?

Comment: It has to be injected in the same manner as `$http`. It's the AngularJS implementation of the promise/defer pattern.

Comment: @CodeZilla ok, but now it returns `{"promise":{}}` instead of nothing so I still cannot access my data, any Ideas?

Comment: Try using "then" instead of "success". What does the alert show? I dont think using "success" is a problem.

Comment: @Codezilla I tried `then` and still same issue, the alert inside the `get` displays `[{"ID":"1","firstname":"John","surname":"Smith"},{"ID":"2","firstname":"Jack","surname":"Jones"}]`

Comment: Yep. Try returning the promise as suggested by @Matt Cooper.

Comment: @Codezilla I was just missing `defer.$apply()` Thanks for your help, if you want to add the $apply to your answer I will accept your answer

Comment: Not sure why it didn't, but now it suddenly is... which is odd

Comment: redundant use of $q.  $http returns a promise object 
    obj.getResponse = function(){                 
        var temp = {};
        return $http.get('hello.php').success(function(data){
            alert(data);
            temp =data;
        });
    }

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch how do you resolve the defered $http returns?

Answer (score 14):

What's happening here is a result of the asynchronous nature of $http.get, When you run $http.get it doesn't run in order. That is, it 'branches off' and runs along side the rest of the code. This is done to accommodate for the server latency.

Here's a bad visualisation.

```
.getResponse Called                Return Temp.
|-------------------|--------------|
                    |---------------------------------|
                    $http.get ~Waiting for Server~    Temp assigned to data.
```

Can you see how Temp is returned before it's been given a value?

Thankfully, you can use what Angular calls a promise, This is a variable which you can return from a function, that gets 'resolved' later. You instantiate a promise like this.

```
var myPromise = $q.defer();
```

You assign values to it by using

```
myPromise.resolve(data);
```

You can then return this promise later in the function, in the normal way. ie.

```
return myPromise.promise
```

Of course, for all of this you need the $q library, which you include in the function parameters.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see Codezilla's answer before I posted, they have the right idea. I'll leave this up as an explanation though.

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation, unfortunately I now just get `{"promise":{}} `

Comment: Terribly sorry! just noticed a bug in my code. You need to return myPromise.promise (as in, the actual promise object!) Should work then. Sorry for leading you astray!

Comment: What I meant was that I still get null, What I get is `{ "promise": {}}` what I think I should be getting it `{"promise": [{"ID":"1","firstname":"John","surname":"Smith"},{"ID":"2","firstname":"Jack","surname":"Jones"}]}`

Comment: I managed to get it, I just needed to call `mypromise.$apply()` Thanks

Comment: Excellent, I wouldn't have expected you to have to $apply() though, I managed to get it working on this plunk (http://plnkr.co/edit/gUqz1Q0jUfXhkAJThTaK) for what it's worth. Good luck!

Comment: @MattCooper Thank you for the return myPromise.promise part. Dint knew that. Voted up! :)

Comment: Sorry. Where and how you used $apply? Trying to understand this promises thing, but ...

Answer (score 0):

```
//in  $httpProvider.interceptors    
if (typeof response.data === 'string') {
   return response;
}
else {
  return response.data;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are you exactly doing in answer. It will be help to understand. Simply writing code not gonaa give clearity.