# Why is the result of defered.promise after defered.resolve(myobject) not the same as myobject

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is, I believe, what is causing the Issue in [this pervious Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130081/what-is-causing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-with-parsejson-an). I have looked [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q) and [here](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2013/03/promises-and-deferred-objects-in-jquery.html) but I still am not understanding what is happening. When I log to the console the value of `temp` I get the result `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31` as expected but when I use `var month = $q.defer()` and `month.resolve(temp)` and try to log the value of `month.promise` I get `[Object object]` instead of the same as temp.

**Is that what should be Expected?**

**if No** - What am I doing incorrect ( [This is why I I'm using $q.defer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101875/how-do-i-return-data-from-a-http-get-inside-a-factory-in-angularjs) in case its a factor)

**if Yes** - How Can I convert `month.promise` to a more consumable form? i.e. if temp is an array how to I access `month.promise` as an array where `temp[0] = month.promise[0]`

below is my code example but all of my controller & service can be found [here](http://gw.gd/O5k2), I basically want to just return an array (or JSON) to my controller instead of `[Object object]`

```
var month = $q.defer();
$http.get('getMonth.php?date=' + date)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    var temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31];
    console.log("Temp : " + temp + " !!!");
    month.resolve(temp);

    //month.resolve(data);
    //console.log("data "+data[0]);
    console.log("resolved " + month);
    console.log("resolved[0] " + month[0]);
    console.log("resolved.promise " + month.promise + " !!!");
    console.log("resolved.promise[0] " + month.promise[0]);

});
```

### UPDATE

on the advice of @CuongLe below I have added the below code and I can successfully log my data but I still get `[Object object]` when I return it

```
var promise = month.promise;
promise.then(
    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: This should be tagged `javascript` and not `java`.

Comment: sorry was meant to be JavaScript, pressed enter too earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [document](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q):

> The purpose of the deferred object is to expose the associated Promise instance as well as APIs that can be used for signaling the successful or unsuccessful completion of the task.

So, you should continue to call `then` with success method to get `temp`

```
var promise = month.promise;
promise.then(
    function(temp){
    console.log(temp);
});
```

Your Service:

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
    .factory('memberFactory', function ($http, $q) {

    var getMonth = function (date) {
        var month = $q.defer();

        $http.get('getMonth.php?date=' + date)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            var temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,...];
            month.resolve(temp);
        });           
        return month.promise;
    }

    return {
        getMonth: getMonth
    };  
});
```

The controller:

```
function myController($scope, memberFactory) {

    promise = memberFactory.getMonth("2013-08-01 06:30:00");

     promise.then(
        function (monthDays) {
           console.log("monthDays : " + monthDays + " !!!");

            var dates = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < monthDays.length; i++) {
                if (i % 7 == 0) dates.push([]);
                dates[dates.length - 1].push(monthDays[i]);
            }

            $scope.dates = dates;
        });

}
```

Comment: @CurongLe I'm sorry I don't understand, I tried this an I just get `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'then'`

Comment: @CurongLe that works to print out on the console but how do I return it, as I still just get `[Object oject]` when I do? I have added the full controller and service code [here](http://gw.gd/O5k2) is that helps

Comment: @CurongLe You are a Legend thank you, it make far more sense now

Answer (score 1):

Use **then** method which returns a promise:

```
obj.getMonth = function (date) {
    var month = $q.defer();
    $http.get('getMonth.php?date=' + date)
        .then(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
            var temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
                16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]; 
            month.resolve(temp); 
        });
    return month.promise;         
}
```

Comment: That allows me to print the entire array using `response =memberFactory.getMonth(date); $scope.month = response` but I still cannot access indiviudal item lik this `$scope.day = response[0]`