# How to handle $http asynchronous issues in angularjs factory service？

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, web

In the factory service js file, I created a service like this:

```
DashboardFactory.restService = function(method) {
var teststatus = "aaa";
switch (method) {

case "getAll":

    $http.get($_REST_API_ROOT_URL + "clients").success(function(data) {
        teststatus = data;
    }).error(function(error) {
        teststatus = 'Unable to load the client data: ' + error.message;
    });
    teststatus = "bbb";
    break;

}
return teststatus;
};
```

In controller, the code is like this:

```
$scope.AllClients=DashboardFactory.restService("getAll","","");
```

I also put the "AllClients" on the html page to monitor the result:

```
{{AllClients}}
```

I think the "AllClients" should show the API data from the remote server. But in reality it always give me "bbb".

What should I do？

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`teststatus` gets set as "bbb" and is returned before the API call is finished since the call is asynchronous.

Refer to [AngularJS $http call in a Service, return resolved data, not promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238928/angularjs-http-call-in-a-service-return-resolved-data-not-promises) for the different ways you can return the data from your API call.

<strike>What you want to do is return `teststatus` at the end of your `.success()`/`.error()` functions rather than outside. That way, it only returns once it finishes the API call and sets it to the data returned by the call.</strike>

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. How do I do it then? I am very new to angularjs.

Comment: Remove the `return teststatus;` line at the end of your function. Then add `return teststatus;` after each time you assign `teststatus` a value inside your `success()` and `error()` functions.

Comment: That will return them from the success method but not from the service.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238928/angularjs-http-call-in-a-service-return-resolved-data-not-promises to return the data from your call.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** You don't NEED to return it at all. You could send in your model to the service `RestService.getAllClients = function(myModel)`, set a property on the model on success `myModel.AllClients = data;` and then display it with `{{myModel.AllClients}}`. Setting the property directly on the passed in model will update the binding automagically.

Example: http://jsbin.com/muxijozofa/edit?html,js,output

**Method 2:** Otherwise you'd need to return the entire `get` call, which will return a `promise`, which you'll then need to resolve on the controller as per f.e [How do I return data from a $http.get() inside a factory in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101875/how-do-i-return-data-from-a-http-get-inside-a-factory-in-angularjs)

**Refactoring tip:** Instead of building a "catch-all" rest service filled with switch-case:s, you could build a general rest-service factory which you then implement for each type of call. So you get one method per type of rest call. Instead of `DashboardFactory.restService`, you'd then call `RestService.getAllClients`, which sets the data or returns a promise per the methods above.

Switch-case is just bad for feature selection, you're hiding functionality and making the code prone to hidden errors.