# asynchronous calls in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a couple of questions on asynchronous functions in angular. I want my service function to be able to return data I get by using $http  and use that data in another function. Let me demonstrate with the current code:

```
dashboard.servicesModule.service('SubscriptionService', function ($http, $q) {

    this.getImportantData= function (param1, param2) {

        var url = "my/url/with/parameters?param1=param1&param2=param2";     

        $http.get(url).then(function(response){         
            console.log("response");
            console.log(response.data); // < --- this actually shows the data i need!!          
            return response.data.vsyData; <--- however, this returns undefined
        }, function(error){
            // some error thingy just in case
        });

    };

    this.getSomeFunctionality = function(param1, param2, param3){
        var importantdata= this.getImportantData(param1, param2);

        // do some filtering on the data with the purpose of returning only what i need

        console.log(importantdata); <--- undefined

    };

    this.getEvenMoreFunctionality = function(param1, param2, param3){
        var importantdata= this.getImportantData(param1, param2);

        // reusing getImportantData again! 

        console.log(importantdata); <--- undefined

    };
});
```

So I have been trying all kinds of things ( like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101875/how-do-i-return-data-from-a-http-get-inside-a-factory-in-angularjs) and [this](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) ) and some inventions of my own. But it starts to seem like there is no way of using the data from the $http.get anywhere else then in its own callback. And since i need the endresult in my controller, it seems like there is no other way then perform the **$http.get(url).success(...some logic here)** in my controller and do the filtering and other manipulation there.

However, I read [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers) and I quote:

> Our controller should be almost completely agnostic as to how data is
>   retrieved and sent, and should only be concerned with the general
>   action of sending and retrieving data to and from the service.

I interpret this as following: my controller should ask the service for the data I need and the service should make sure that it gives the data in the correct form.

The most important question is: how can I make the above code do what it needs to do or would that be impossible?

And am I supposed to do my business logic in my controller? Because [here, in the angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) I basically read that you should do business logic in your controller, but not filtering...

Its probably obvious, but ... I am an angular newbie :-).
Thanks!

Comment: You don't assign a value to `dates` anywhere, so it is obviously undefined.

Comment: @muenchdo your are right, i wanted to be too fast when editing the code to leave company sensitive data out. I am going to modify my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.getImportantData= function (param1, param2) {
    var url = "my/url/with/parameters?param1=param1&param2=param2";     

    return $http.get(url);
};

this.getSomeFunctionality = function(param1, param2, param3){
    this.getImportantData(param1, param2)
    .then(function(response){         
        console.log(response.data.vsyData);
    }, function(error){
        // some error thingy just in case
    });
};

this.getEvenMoreFunctionality = function(param1, param2, param3){
    this.getImportantData(param1, param2)
    .then(function(response){         
        console.log(response.data.vsyData);
    }, function(error){
        // some error thingy just in case
    });
};
```

You can't get data from a method which has an asynchronous call. You can return promise, and then you can get data from promise.

Comment: So basically the getSomeFunctionality function cannot return the end result (for example some mathematical validation and filtering of the data)  to my controller? I can filter inside the .then(function(response){} but I cannot return the result to my controller? If so, there is no point is putting that logic in a separate service i guess?

Answer (score 2):

For an assyncronous request you cannot make imediate return statement, tha main javascript thread will not wait for request resolution. I really recomend use [`$q` API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), is the angular implementation of Kris Kowal's Q promises/deferred systems.

```
function getSomething(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('foo/bar')
        .success(function(data){
            $deferred.resolve(data);
        });
    return deferred.promise();
}

getSomething().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Or you can return directly the `$http` promise. In case you want to remove the `.then()` from your controller, you can use [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) with the `resolve` option that supports `$q` promises and create routes that self resolve your data, so you just inject them in controller, free of the `$q` proceedings.

**UPDATE 1 - Practical example of resolving dependencies in routes**

```
$routeProvider.when('/items/list', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/item/list',
    controller: 'ListItemsCtrl',
    resolve: {
      items: function(ItemsService) {
        return ItemsService.getItems(); // getItems returns a promise like 'return $http.get('/items');'
      }
    }
  });

//controller
function ListItemsCtrl($scope, items){
    //do something with your items
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the update! this seems very useful to look into!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSomething(){
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.get('foo/bar')
    .success(function(data){
        $deferred.resolve(data);
    });
return deferred.promise();
}
  getSomething().then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Please add a little explain to your answer